# clean way to identify if user from intranet or internet

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

how can I determine if a user is accessing my application from the internet or intranet?

I'm very confused about the source and security of the IIS server variables.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx
for example, is Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"] blank for remote users?

also, the documentation on Environment.UserDomainName at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx
makes me think it is possible to game this by naming the computer name equal to a domain name I'm checking for

Ideally, I'd just like to ...

```
if ( [ ... user is not remote ... ] && Enironment.UserDomainName == "TargetLocalDomainName" )
    var username = Environment.UserName;
    PrepareLocalUserSession(username);
    RedirectToHomePage();
 } 
 //else
 [... redirect to remote login page ...]
```

so my question is how do I determine if the user is coming from a remote destination? I'd strongly prefer to use something less messy than IP checking if possible.

Thanks

---

EDIT

I thought my approach above was so horrible that I wanted to post a sane approach

```
var hostAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

bool localUser = hostAddress.StartsWith("192.") | hostAddress.StartsWith("10.") | hostAddress.StartsWith("172.") || HttpRequest.Current.Request.IsLocal;

string username = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].split( new char[]{"/"})[0]; 
string domain   = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].split( new char[]{"/"})[1];

if( localUser && domain == "TargetLocalDomainName" ){
   PrepareLocalUserSession(username);
   RedirectToHomePage();
} 

//else
[... redirect to remote login page ...]
```

Comment: note to self: if use IP approach, allow for local debugging requests as well => ' HttpRequest.Current.Request.IsLocal | '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you can not use the `Environment` class to get information about the user making the request to your server.  `Environment` accesses the local computer's environment, so you'll always get the server's details.  Nothing in there is going to tell you thing one about the client.

All client information available to the server will be in the `Request` object.  If you use authentication on your website you can get the user to log in, then check the user's security details in [`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.logonuseridentity%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for example.

This still won't tell you where the client actually is however.  Testing the user's login domain will only tell you if the user has authenticated against the domain, not whether the client is on your local network.  If your website is accessible from outside your network (using NAT for instance, or mixed public + private address on the server) you'll still have to check the IP address on the request to make sure it's in the local network.

So the short answer is that you can't do this without checking the IP address against known internal network ranges.

Comment: nice catch on the evironment. it may work for a non-client server scenario, but it will almost definately fail for web purposes.