# How to check PC is connected with Internet or Intranet without IP address and Ping method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I check PC is Connected with Intranet or Internet without using Ping method and IP address in C#?

Comment: Forget C# for a moment - what do you want the check to be at a pure network level. What counts as "connected with intranet", *precisely*?

Comment: I want to check  My PC is connected with Intranet or Internet, In intranet I don't have access for  some Websites

Comment: So test whether you have access to one of those web sites... that's what you're really trying to use, right?

Comment: I want to find it out its internet  or Intranet without checking website access(Ping Method) and IP Address

Comment: But *why*? What benefit is there in taking a proxy signal for "I can get to that website" over actually checking whether you can get to the relevant web site?

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, I needed to have a service up in a LAN network and check Network status from time to time. I eventually used this:

```cs
static readonly INetworkListManager NetworkListManager = new NetworkListManager();
// ...
while (NetworkListManager.IsConnected) {
  // do something...
}

// loop is over. no internet!
while (!NetworkListManager.IsConnected) {
  // wait for reconnection...
}
```

In my case that achieved what I needed, and with some testing it also worked on my WAN environment. But as always, there's no 100% correct assumption when it comes to interacting with other hardware. **Incorrect result can happen**, so put in as much as test you can.

Comment: I am getting "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010108): The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" this exception while using

NETWORKLIST.INetworkListManager.GetNetworks(NLM_ENUM_NETWORK Flags)

Kindly let me know Why I am getting this exception and How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something i used for a game of mine to detect if there is a network connection without it even touching or talking the router or other devices:

```
// Recommended for clean code
public static bool InternetConnection() => System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

The code above is just the same as:

```
public static bool InternetConnection() { 
    return System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable(); 
}
```

Comment: This condition will return True for both Internet and Intranet

Comment: yes. Isnt it what you are looking for? @Krishna 
It essentially checks if the current device is even connected to the router at all

Comment: I want to Know , where I have  connected Like  I have connected with Internet ,I have Connected with Intranet,I want know specifically

Comment: well i guess you could take a look at this link then and see how it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435503/clean-way-to-identify-if-user-from-intranet-or-internet] @Krishna